# SQL Server - GROUP BY on one column

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to get orders from an orderview. In my view I do have some rows with exactly the same values, but I want to group these values on orderid and take the sum of the quantity of that order.

My view results something like:

```
 Order_id   Customer_id   Article_id   Delivery_date   Quantity
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PR10.001   11            20.001a      17-04-2013      1
 PR10.001   11            20.001a      17-04-2013      1
 PR10.001   11            20.001a      17-04-2013      1
 PR13.001   15            41.022b      19-04-2013      1
 PR13.001   15            41.022b      19-04-2013      1
```

I want to do something like:

```
SELECT Order_id, Customer_id Article_id, Delivery_date, sum(Quantity)
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Order_id
```

To get something like:

```
 Order_id   Customer_id   Article_id   Delivery_date   Quantity
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PR10.001   11            20.001a      17-04-2013      3
 PR13.001   15            41.022b      19-04-2013      2
```

But I know grouping by one single column is not possible, otherwise you'll get the message:

> [...] is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in
>   either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Is there another possibility or workaround to group by one specific column in SQL Server?

Comment: I'm sorry, there was something wrong with my example, I've editted it, it should be clear now

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use a [`CTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with [`SUM(Quantity)OVER(PARTITION BY Order_id)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) + [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to pick out the desired row from the order-group:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT order_id, 
                customer_id, 
                article_id, 
                delivery_date, 
                quantity=Sum(quantity) 
                           OVER( 
                             partition BY order_id), 
                rn = Row_number() 
                       OVER( 
                         partition BY order_id 
                         ORDER BY delivery_date ASC) 
         FROM   orders) 
SELECT order_id, 
       customer_id, 
       article_id, 
       delivery_date, 
       quantity 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0c82/2/0)

<strike>However, your desired result seems to be incorrect</strike> (question edited)

This is my result:

```
ORDER_ID    CUSTOMER_ID ARTICLE_ID  DELIVERY_DATE   QUANTITY
PR10.001    11          20.001a         17-04-2013  3
PR13.001    15          41.022b         19-04-2013  2
```

Comment: Seems like ARTICLE_ID can be multiple for each ORDER_ID, in above CTE sample first is picked, isn't a complete result.

Comment: @harsh: OP has not mentioned that he also wants  group by the article so i left it as it is. Otherwise he could simply add the ARTICLE_ID  to the `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: First of all: Tim is right, it's not neccessary to group by Article_id because each order has just 1 sort of article. Second, what a terrible and complicated work-around as if you used to work with MySQL where it's possible to just use 1 group by, but it work GREAT now! All credits to you, thanks!

Comment: @JorikvanOnna: It's not complicated once you've understood how [**ranking functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) work, they are really powerful. The order by in the `ROW_NUMBER` also enables to specify which row exactly you want to get from the group. The `CTE` makes it also more redable and easier to maintain.

Comment: +1 I liked the `CTE` approach. After the correction made to question, my answer isn't valid anymore.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming the other columns are functionally dependent on the grouping column, the simplest answers are either

a. Group by the other columns as well:

```
SELECT Order_id, Customer_id, Article_id, Delivery_date, sum(Quantity)
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Order_id, Customer_id, Article_id, Delivery_date
```

or

b. Use an aggregate function such as `max`:

```
SELECT Order_id, max(Customer_id), max(Article_id), max(Delivery_date), sum(Quantity)
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Order_id
```

My personal preference is the second approach, as I think it is clearer than the first in indicating which items are actually required for grouping, as opposed to which are merely being grouped to get round the ungrouped/unaggregated column problem.

Comment: That was my logic too, but when I try to make a new view, I get some new problems: At your first solution I get: "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.", which should be caused by some columns I haven't included in my example. Your second doesn't work neither because I have some varchar columns which does not support max()

Comment: @JorikvanOnna: I would expect varchar columns to always support `max`, but not necessarily text, ntext or image data types. Since this appears to be the underlying cause of your problem, I suggest updating your question to include this information. Tim's answer should work, even with this limitation; another approach would be to group by the grouping column and include the aggregated value in an inline view / CTE, then join to the other tables that include the problem columns - this would require more information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario it doesn't seem correct to group-by Order_id having varying Article_id. You expected result seems wrong. It should be:

PR10.001 has two Article_id 20.001a, 41.022b and total quantity 4 (not 3)

Is your expectation is to get total quantity for each Order_id but retaining varying column too then you need to decide on expected result? something like:

```
 Order_id   Customer_id   Article_id            Delivery_date   Quantity
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PR10.001   11            20.001a, 41.022b      17-04-2013      4
 PR13.001   15            41.022b               19-04-2013      2
```

Comment: my expected result was wrong indeed, but I editted it, should be right now

Answer (score 0):

I have used similar kind of table as yours. names would be different jsu to test it fast.
Please refer to the following query. Modify names as you require.

```
select ordid,customerid,articleid,SUM(cast(quantity as numeric)) quantity from test_stack group by ordid,customerid,articleid
```