# Grouping table by only one field with linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have table with 7 fields in MSSQL server MDF file that imports CSV files and need to generate few reports for them.

I'm accessing to database with EF and linq from C#.

Is it possible, and how to execute linq query similar to this mysql query?

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3, f4 FROM tbl
GROUP BY f1
HAVING COUNT(f1) > 10
```

I have found [SQL Server - GROUP BY on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033448/sql-server-group-by-on-one-column) but it's classic SQL, and as a beginner, i can't translate it to Linq.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the article you referenced, the syntax of your SQL is invalid, because not all of the elements in the select list are part of the GROUP BY clause.

If your intent is the following:

```
SELECT f1, f2, f3, f4 FROM tbl
GROUP BY f1, f2, f3, f4
HAVING COUNT(f1) > 10
```

Then the equivalent LINQ is:

```
var result = tbl.GroupBy(a => new {a.f1, a.f2, a.f3, a.f4}).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 10).Select(group => group.Key);
```

Or

```
 var result = 
        from a in tbl 
        group a by new { a.f1, a.f2, a.f3, a.f4 } into grp 
        where grp.Count() > 10
        select grp.Key;
```